# Scanning the folder I created

Tags: php, html, forms

**Hello!** Newbie here. I am trying to scan the folder that I created using form. The folder creation is successful but each time I try to use **scandir()** on it, the result is of the folder where my php file is located(the folder I created is located inside xampp/htdocs). Any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

**Here's my code:**

```
    <?php
        function create_folder(){
            echo '<div class = "wrapper">';
                echo '<div class = "box1">';
                    echo '<form action = "Item123.php" method="post">';
                        echo 'Folder name:<input type="text" name="fname">';
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Create Folder"><br><br>';
                        echo '<input type="submit" name = "submit1" value = "See folder contents">';
                    echo '</form>';
                echo '</div>';
            
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("You must indicate a name for the folder")';
                    echo '</script>';
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'window.location.href = "Item123.php"';
                    echo '</script>';
                }
                else{
                    $fname  = $_POST['fname'];
                    $fName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fname);
                    $dir = "/xampp/htdocs/";
                    $loc = $dir.$fName."/";
                    $create = mkdir($dir.$fName."/");
                    echo $create;
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Folder created!")';
                    echo '</script>';
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';

                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
                $fname  = $_POST['fname'];
                $fName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fname);
                $dir = "/xampp/htdocs/";
                $loc = $dir. $fName."/";
                $filelist = scandir($loc, 0);
                if(file_exists($loc)){
                    foreach($filelist as $list){
                        if(is_file($list)){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $list . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . filetype($list) . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . filesize($list) . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($list)) . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . is_readable($list) . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . is_writable($list) . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

?>
```

Comment: Did you actually enter the folder name into the text input field again, before you clicked your `See folder contents` button?

Comment: The value of `$fname` will not be preserved between requests. Every time you run your PHP script it's like it never ran before. All variables etc are reset. You would need to enter the folder name again into the form in order for it to work.

Comment: Hello, CBroe! Yes that's what I did, that's why I had the same variables on the See folder contents button...did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As @ADyson said, there is a separate PHP-process for every time you call the script. So the contents of `$_POST['fname']` are forgotten when calling again with `submit1`.

Since it's the same form you could just include the folder-name again:

```php
echo 'Folder name:<input type="text" name="fname" value=' . $_POST['fname'] . '>';
```

Thus it will be send again when submitting the form a second time.
Side effect is, when you change the input box after creating a folder, the `submit1` button will throw an error if the newly entered folder does not exist.

--

Another possibility would be: storing it in `$_SESSION`. That is, in very short, the only variable which survives until the next call.

```php
                    $create = mkdir($dir.$fName."/");
                    echo $create;
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $fName; // store
...

                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
                $fName = $_SESSION['fname']; //restore
```

It depends in what behavior you want: This way after clicking `submit1` one will always see the contents *of the last created folder*, even if meanwhile the contents of the input-box changed.

--

Btw. [mkdir returns a boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), so

```php
$create = mkdir($dir.$fName."/");
echo $create;
```

does not make much sense. Better do:

```php
if (mkdir($dir.$fName."/") {
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("Folder created!")';
  echo '</script>';
} else {
  echo "Error creating $dir.$fName";
}
```